# how to stop zoom in and zoom out in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphviz, react-vis, react-graph-vis

I am using the below package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-graph-vis

could you please tell me **how to stop zoom in and zoom out of all nodes**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-c9tnhw?file=index.js

here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-c9tnhw?file=index.js

```
const options = {
    layout: {
      hierarchical: false
    },
    edges: {
      color: "#F0E"
    },
    nodes: {
      fixed: true
    },
    height: "600px"
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your options object should look like:

```
const options = {
    layout: {
      hierarchical: false
    },
    edges: {
      color: "#F0E"
    },
    height: "600px",
    interaction: {
      zoomView: false
    },
  };
```

So just add:

```
    interaction: {
      zoomView: false
    }
```